# Can not determine between domains after proxy forwarding to nginx

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, proxy

I have nginx configured as a proxy, while apache is listening to port 80. Somehow it seems not to be possible to distinguish between domain names in nginx.

apache conf:

```
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:80>
    ServerName staging.static.domain.com

    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8000/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:80>
    ServerName staging.domain.com

    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8000/
</VirtualHost>
```

nginx conf

```
server {
    listen       8000;
    server_name  "staging.static.domain.com";
}

server {
    listen       8000;
    server_name  "staging.domain.com";
}
```

The first server will always be executed, regardless of the domain name.

How can I distinguish between the two without chaning the port?

Comment: Why are the names quoted? That is probably the problem. Server names are used literally.

Comment: Just found the solution. In apache there needs to be the command "ProxyPreserveHost On"